# Cannot access Eloquent attributes on Twig

Tags: php, eloquent, twig, slim

I am trying to access an Eloquent attribute with Twig in Slim, and getting an error.

I have a Field and a Type object, and the relationship is as follows

```
class Field extends \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model {

protected $table = 'fields';

public function type()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('models\Type');
}
```

When doing `{{ f }}` (being f a field), the output is this:

```
{"field_id":"1","field_name":"Your name","form_id":"2","type_id":"1","placeholder":"Please give us your name"}
```

And when doing `{{ f.type }}`, the result is:

> Message: An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Object of class Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo could not be converted to string") in "pages/editform.html" at line 97.

If I try to do `{{ f.type.name }}`, doesn't throw up an exception but doesn't print anything either.

If I do it in PHP

```
    $fields = $form->fields;
    var_dump($fields[0]->type->name);
```

The value gets output correctly.

Any ideas?,
Thanks

Comment: I don't really know twig but for some reason it seems to call the function instead of letting Laravel do it's magic. You could try this: `{{ f.type.name.get() }}`

Comment: Didn't work, for now I have had to resort to this: 

`public function getTypeString() { $type = Type::find($this->type_id); return $type->name; }`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same issue and stumbled upon this question.  After solving it myself, I thought I'd try to help you out.

Try doing a Eager Load on the model:

```
Field::with('type')->get()
```

This should allow you to do the following with no other issues.

```
{{ f.type }}
```

See more info here: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#eager-loading

Comment: Worked like a charm, interesting concept to learn, thank you so much!

Comment: Now I got it! Thanks guys.

Answer (score 8):

**If you don't want to do an eager load**, you can override the magic `__isset` method in your `Field` class to return `true` for the `type` relationship property:

```
public function __isset($name)
{
    if (in_array($name, [
        'type'
    ])) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return parent::__isset($name);
    }
}
```

**Explanation**

The problem is in the interaction between how Eloquent implements the "dynamic property" for a relation (in your case, `f.type`), and the rules that Twig uses for accessing "attributes" of a variable.

From the Twig documentation:

> For convenience's sake `foo.bar` does the following things on the PHP layer:
>
> - check if `foo` is an array and `bar` a valid element;
> - if not, and if `foo` is an object, **check that `bar` is a valid property**;
> - if not, and if `foo` is an object, check that `bar` is a valid method (even if `bar` is the constructor - use `__construct()` instead);
> - if not, and if `foo` is an object, check that `getBar` is a valid method;
> - if not, and if `foo` is an object, check that `isBar` is a valid method;
> - if not, return a null value.
>
> `foo['bar']` on the other hand only works with PHP arrays:
>
> - check if `foo` is an array and `bar` a valid element;
> - if not, return a null value.

The key here is the part where it says "check that bar is a valid property".  This means that on the level of PHP, Twig is calling `isset` on `$f->type`.  Eloquent [implements the magic `__isset` method in `Model`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/9f80fe4cb3d938f2ae054055f5affc0ec799cde9/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L3455-L3465), so you might think that this wouldn't be a problem.

However, take a look at how it actually implements `__isset` for model relations:

```
/**
 * Determine if an attribute exists on the model.
 *
 * @param  string  $key
 * @return bool
 */
public function __isset($key)
{
    return (isset($this->attributes[$key]) || isset($this->relations[$key])) ||
            ($this->hasGetMutator($key) && ! is_null($this->getAttributeValue($key)));
}
```

It determines whether a relation is "set" by looking in its array of loaded relationships (`isset($this->relations[$key])`).  The problem is that if `type` hasn't been loaded yet, Eloquent will say that it is not "set".

Thus when Twig looks at `$f->type`, it will think that `type` is not a valid *property*, and move on to the next rule:

> ...if `foo` is an object, check that `bar` is a valid method

So now it will look for the *method* `type()`, which it finds.  The only problem?  `type()` (the method) returns a `Relation` (specifically, a `BelongsTo`), rather than a `Type` object.  And `BelongsTo` objects aren't models.

If you want Twig to know that the property `$f->type` does indeed exist, you have two choices:

- You can eager-load the related `Type` object along with your `Field`, as suggested by @roger-collins, or;
- You can overload the `__isset` magic method in `Field`:

`public function __isset($name)
    {
        if (in_array($name, [
            'type'
        ])) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return parent::__isset($name);
        }
    }`

This will force Twig to recognize that `type` is a valid property for `Field`, even before the related model has actually been loaded.

Comment: FYI, small typo in the `isset` code. Missing a `)` after `type` : `])) {`