# Eloquent Relationship returning but not giving me the attributes

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, twig

The eloquent relationship I have defined is returning the belongsTo object but not actually giving me access to any of the attributes that should be inside of it.

Relationship in Step.php

```
public function profession()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(__NAMESPACE__.'\\Profession', 'id', 'profession_id');
}
```

Relationship in Profession.php

```
public function steps() {
    return $this->hasMany(__NAMESPACE__ . '\\Step', 'id', 'profession_id');
}
```

Code I am using to return the belongsTo relationship.

```
{{ dd(step.profession) }}
```

The response I am getting is of the belongsTo type but it just doesn't contain any information about the profession.

Comment: I don't know twig but this might be relevant http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29514081/cannot-access-eloquent-attributes-on-twig

Comment: You missed the part where you show us how you actually query the relation, so it can be then used in the view.

Comment: Please not that belongsTo only takes on key, the foreign_key. You can delete the profession_id here. Further class can be replaced with Profession::class (PHP 5.5 >=)

Comment: @J.Eggerstedt Thanks for your response but I didn't manage to get this to work.

Comment: @lesssugar That is done with the code below and then I use a for loop to loop through each individual one and print out the values. I can get it all to work apart from this profession bit.

    $steps = Step::orderBy('name', 'asc')->get()->all();

Comment: @LukeBetter Your calling `Step` model only. You need to eager-load the relation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try Eager Loading the professions like:

```
Step::with('profession')->orderBy('name', 'asc')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your relationships to

Relationship in Step.php

```
public function profession()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(__NAMESPACE__.'\\Profession', 'profession_id');
}
```

Relationship in Profession.php

```
public function steps() {
   return $this->hasMany(__NAMESPACE__ . '\\Step', 'profession_id');
}
```

The second argument of the **belongsTo** and **hasMany** should be the **foreign key** not the **primary key**

Comment: I done this but I am still experiencing the same problem. I have tried a fair few combinations and it is still not working, sadly.